# I cannot understand @State variable behavior

Tags: swiftui

I cannot make sense of the @State variable behavior.

Let's start from a simple example: to open different sheets depending on the button pressed.

```
struct TestView: View {
    @State private var sheetToShow = 0
    @State private var showSheet = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Show 1") {
                sheetToShow = 1
                showSheet = true
            }
            Button("Show 2") {
                sheetToShow = 2
                showSheet = true
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet, onDismiss: {
        }, content: {
            MySheet(showSheet: showSheet, sheetToShow: sheetToShow)
        }
        )
    }
}


struct MySheet: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss
    var showSheet: Bool
    var sheetToShow: Int

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if sheetToShow == 0 {
                Text("Sheet 0")
                Text("showSheet: \(showSheet.description)")
                Text("sheetToShow: \(sheetToShow)")
            }

            if sheetToShow == 1 {
                Text("Sheet 1")
                Text("showSheet: \(showSheet.description)")
                Text("sheetToShow: \(sheetToShow)")
            }

            if sheetToShow == 2 {
                Text("Sheet 2")
                Text("showSheet: \(showSheet.description)")
                Text("sheetToShow: \(sheetToShow)")
            }

            Button("Close") {
                dismiss()
            }
        }
        .frame(width: 200, height: 300)
    }
}
```

When I push the 'Show 1' button first time the sheet opens but it shows:

- Sheet 0
- showSheet false
- sheetToShow 0

Hence, as far as I understand, both the variables showSheet and sheetToShow have not changed but the sheet show up anyway.

From now on, the behavior gets back to normal: each button makes the right sheet to show up.

I have made everything working using a simple View Model but it looks like too much just to open a sheet.

```
@Observable class Model {
    var sheetToShow = 0
    var showSheet = false
}

struct TestView: View {
    @State var model = Model()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Show 1") {
                model.sheetToShow = 1
                model.showSheet = true
            }
            Button("Show 2") {
                model.sheetToShow = 2
                model.showSheet = true
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $model.showSheet, onDismiss: {
        }, content: {
            MySheet(showSheet: model.showSheet, sheetToShow: model.sheetToShow)
        }
        )
    }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong or this is the expected behavior?

By the way, I get exactly the same behavior on iOS and macOS.

Comment: It's because you have't accessed `showSheet` in body so just add `showSheet` to the sheet closure's capture list. You need to get a state in body for body to be called when the state is set.